# set operations over Z3 expressions

Tags: z3

Are there functions defining set operations  , e.g  `set, intersection, union, members` etc , over Z3 expressions ?    Also, are there functions to check if a formula is a `cnf` or `dnf` ?

If not I can try to implement them in the z3utils file.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Python sets to encode sets of expressions. The only problem is that the operator `__eq__` for Z3Py expressions will build a new expression instead of comparing whether to expressions are equal or not. To fix that, we can use a wrapper that invokes the correct compares Z3 expressions. Here is a sample (available online at [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/QYGf)).

```py
class AstRefKey:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.n.hash()
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.n.eq(other.n)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.n)

def askey(n):
    assert isinstance(n, AstRef)
    return AstRefKey(n)

x = Int('x')
s = set()
s.add(askey(x+1))
s.add(askey(x))
print s
print askey(x + 1) in s
s2 = set()
s2.add(askey(x+2))
s2.add(askey(x))
print s2
print s.union(s2)
```

The only inconvenience is that we have to keep using `askey`. We can avoid this inconvenience by defining a class `ASTSet` that wraps a Python `set` object an invokes `askey` for us.

Regarding, `dnf` and `cnf` recognizers. This functionality is not exposed in the external APIs.